# Why doesn't setInterval work properly to change an element's color?

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I have created a function `addElements()` which changes an image, background color of the body and text color of a p tag. Now when I run the following code, the image changes at the `setInterval` infinetely but the colors do not change even once.

```
function addElements() {
  var img = document.getElementById('img');
  var image = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];
  img.src = image;

  var name = document.getElementById('name');
  var color = colors = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
  name.setAttribute('color', color);
};

window.addEventListener('load', setInterval(addElements, 4321));
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve]. Use the life demo feature of the question editor.

Comment: `name.setAttribute('color', color);` — No element, that isn't obsolete (and should not be used), has a `color` attribute.

Comment: `window.addEventListener('load', setInterval(addElements, 4321));` — The use of `addEventListener` here is pointless. You need to pass it a function, not the return value of `setInterval`.

Comment: 4321 is a strange interval :)

Comment: Why are you replacing the colors array? `color = colors = colors[...`  seems wrong here

Comment: `colors = colors[x]` surely ruins the `colors` variable by replacing a reference to the array with a reference to one of its elements.  That might work _once_.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the line

```
var color = colors = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
```

contains an error. You should remove  `= colors`

so that the line  is

```
var color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
```

Comment: embarassing mistake. i removed it and it works fine. thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

instead of `name.setAttribute('color', color);`

use

```
name.style.color = color;
```

Comment: I don't think this is an issue here. It seems unneeded tbh